# Child OnInitializedAsync called before parent OnInitializedAsync finishes

Tags: .net-core, razor, blazor-webassembly

I've got MainLayout.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
    var user = authState.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var authToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
        ApiClient.SetAuthorization(authToken);

        Console.WriteLine($"User {user.Identity.Name} is authenticated. {authToken}");
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Login");

        Console.WriteLine("User is NOT authenticated.");
    }
}
```

And site Index.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    this.Data = await ApiClient.GetData();
}
```

Unfortunately ApiClient.GetData is run first before I even set the Bearer token. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to this.
Do not load the parent control in async, rather:
protected override void OnInitialized()

And you can also place the child load in this form:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)

I believe I also had a cleaner solution for this a while ago, but I will need to dig through my code to find it for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _localStorage.GetItemAsync doenst have Sync method to Gettem thats why I have to stick with Async unfortunately.